# Run JavaScript function on multiple elements..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fonts, size, containers

I'm very new to JavaScript (and of course jQuery), so I'm seeking a little help...
This JavaScript function changes font size depending on the container div.

http://jsfiddle.net/pthjU/

I need it to work for all divs (of a certain class, eventually) - but it only grabs the info from the first one, and resizes them all according to that one.
Any thoughts?

Not looking for a copy/paste answer, I want to get through this properly.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to handle each element independently, you can do that in your plugin, by doing a [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) loop there, instead of this:

```
$.fn.textfill = function(options) {
    var fontSize = options.maxFontPixels;
    var ourText = $('span', this);
    var maxHeight = $(this).height();
    var maxWidth = $(this).width();
    var textHeight;
    var textWidth;
    do {
        ourText.css('font-size', fontSize);
        textHeight = ourText.height();
        textWidth = ourText.width();
        fontSize = fontSize - 1;
    } while (textHeight > maxHeight || textWidth > maxWidth && fontSize > 3);
    return this;
}
```

It should be like this:

```
$.fn.textfill = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var fontSize = options.maxFontPixels;
        var ourText = $('span', this);
        var maxHeight = $(this).height();
        var maxWidth = $(this).width();
        var textHeight;
        var textWidth;
        do {
            ourText.css('font-size', fontSize);
            textHeight = ourText.height();
            textWidth = ourText.width();
            fontSize = fontSize - 1;
        } while (textHeight > maxHeight || textWidth > maxWidth && fontSize > 3);
    });
};
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/5uKqj/)

---

As an aside, from the old method...`this` is already a jQuery object inside a plugin (note how I'm calling [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) directly on it), there's no need to wrap it in another jQuery object (cloning it).  You *do* need to wrap it in my second example *inside* the loop, since inside the [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) you're referring to individual DOM elements, not jQuery objects.

Comment: Ah I see now, thank you very much. Unfortunately I'm too noob to get this working outside of JsFiddle - I call the function after $(window).load, and double-checked I've included jquery... Perhaps I've missed something else? :S

Comment: Oh, just forgot to set margins and padding to 0 for paragraphs =.=

Answer (score 0):

add .each() into

```
$('.post').each().textfill({ maxFontPixels: 500 }); <--- not sure if this works.. but

$('.post').each(function(){
    jQuery(this).textfill({ maxFontPixels: 500 });
});
```

Should definately work.

Alan

Comment: Hah! Simple as that, the second one you suggested works a charm.
Thank you very much. Baby-steps ;)